# Map MySql datetime to hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime

I have a `datetime` field in my MySql database. A typical entry looks like this: `2015-08-26 11:45:48`.

But by the time it reaches my app the hours, minutes and seconds are always `00:00:00`.

This is the mapping entry:

```
<property name="listingTime" column="listing_time"/>
```

The field in my `Java` class is

```
private java.sql.Timestamp startTime;
```

I tried setting various types for the `listingTime` property in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` but it doesn't change the all zeroes. What am I missing?

Comment: how do you get `Timestamp` ?

Comment: How do you mean? It's mapped like I wrote in the question.

Comment: @Eddy: Why did you chose `java.sql.Timestamp` type of field instead of `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @beemaster it seems to be better for integration with Hibernate / Spring

Answer (score 7):

Better use annotations like this:

```
...
@Column
@Type(type="timestamp")
private Date listing_time;
```

OR you can do it this way, and if you don't want it to change see the "updateable"

```
@Column(name = "created", nullable = false, updatable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;
```

Comment: I tried type="timestamp" in my Product.hbm.xml but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

With JPA, Use temporal.

```
<entity class="com.package.of.my.entities.MyEntity" name="MyEntity">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="startTime">
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

With Hibernate (hbm.xml), User

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.package.of.my.entities">
    <class name="MyEntity">
        <timestamp name="startTime" column="START_TIME" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Or in annotation

```
@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.sql.Timestamp startTime;
```

Alternatively is to use Long datatype to store your  timestamp.
So, using annotation, you declare in your entity :

```
@Basic
private Long startTime;

public void setStartTime(Long startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public Long getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}
```

and in your logic, you do

```
Date dateStartTime = new Date();
entity.setStartTime(dateStartTime.getTime());
```

To set the date property...and

```
Date dateStartTime = new Date(entity.getStartTime());
```

To get the date property.

Comment: I'm using hbm.xml. This is my property:  <property name="startTime" type="timestamp" column="listing_time"/>. How do you specify temporal in it?

Comment: There you go, I edited my answer, adding hbm.xml sample